# UIView Animation in TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, uiviewanimation

Tearing my hair out here, any thoughts?

I have a tableview that when it loads, Section 1 is a scrollView that starts with it's content offset scrolled all the way to the end.  Section 2, is blank and I get data from my API, at which point I refresh the tableView.  I want to animate the scrollView back to contentOffset 0,0 slowly and under my control (i.e. with a UIView Animation Block) the problem is that animation completes instantaneously. I am assuming that the reload of the tableView causes this problem, but not sure, I want the tableView to reload and then run my animation.  I have tried `dispatch_sync` to just block the main queue which of course causes deadlock and that's not my goal :P

Here is my animation code, fairly simple.

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         scrollView_.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
```

This is called in my load data completion block after `[tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reloadData` will remove all your cells from the view and insert them again.

The easist solution I see is to reload only the second section, not the first one with the scrollview.